# jupyter not working from terminal [mac m1] zsh

Tags: macos, installation, conda

I have installed `Miniforge` on my macbook air m1, and then did the following steps to successfully install jupyter and launch it:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
```

```
mkdir data-science
cd data-science
```

```
conda create --prefix ./env python=3.8
conda activate ./env
```

```
conda install -y jupyter 
conda install pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn tqdm
```

Then: I launched Jupyter this way:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Everything worked fine. But when I exited the terminal and opened again and typed:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I got this error: `zsh: command not found: jupyter`

What is the problem?

I know that this is a path problem, but even when I go to `env` environment, and I run `jupyter notebook` I get the same command error.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think you need to reactivate the environment each time you restart the terminal sesion.

conda activate ./env

then run your code